# Community Guest User on email send action: "EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo"

Tags: community, email, visual-workflow, guest-user

I can not send an email from a flow when I'm a guest user. This is the error that I receive:

SEND EMAIL: send_email

emailBody = Content here
emailAddresses = {!Email_Address_Input.value} (test.test@testcom)

senderAddress = claims.test@test.com

senderType = OrgWideEmailAddress

emailSubject = {!subject_template} (All OK)

**EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo.**

I suspect it has something to do with the guest user permissions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of the Summer 2020 release and change the guest user permissions.

The problem turned out to be that the community users were not able to access OrgWideAddresses from the community.

The solution was to set the flow "Run In Mode" to be "system mode without sharing".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the latest guest user permissions. Try removing the sendertype from the alert/ recreate the flow in system mode.