# Schedule flow is not sending out email with OrgWideEmailAddress

Tags: scheduled-flow

I have a schedule flow that is collecting leads info then sending out a confirmation email to them. The only sender type that worked is DefaultWorkflowUser.

Based on this link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KOtkQAG
OrgwideEmailAddress should also work (like i added in Automated process settings) but it is returning an error on the flow.
"Unhandled Fault has occured in this flow"

Is there another setting I can use? because emails are needed to be sent from that address.

[image][image]

Comment: is your org wide address enabled   for particular profiles  or all profiles.   if it is for particular profiles, it will not work for automated user.    you need to enable it for ll profiles.

Comment: it is for all profiles

Comment: is the org wide email address `verified`?  is the sender email address the same as the org-wide-email-address?

Comment: It is verified in the Org wide email setting. I set it to User selection. All profiles can use.

Comment: Your error message says `Unhandled fault in flow` - you should get an email containing details of the error. What does it say? Use [edit]

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313408/community-guest-user-on-email-send-action-entityobject-can-not-be-initialized
I was able to fixed it by following this post. Thank you for reminding me of the error line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Community Guest User on email send action: "EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313408/community-guest-user-on-email-send-action-entityobject-can-not-be-initialized)

Error is fixed by changing the running mode of the flow to Run in system mode without sharing